# Flutter in app purchase queryPastPurchses BillingResponse.serviceDisconnected error

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I want to check if user bought non consumable item which remove ads.
So when App starts(splash activity), I run code below.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _checkPurchasedItem();
    super.initState();
  }

_checkPurchasedItem() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    InAppPurchaseConnection _iap = InAppPurchaseConnection.instance;
    final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await _iap.queryPastPurchases();

    if(response.error != null) {
      debugPrint("splash: check purchased item error");
      debugPrint("error: " + response.error.message);
      debugPrint("error: " + response.error.code);
      debugPrint("error: " + response.error.details.toString());
      return;
    }
    for (PurchaseDetails details in response.pastPurchases) {
      if (details.productID == nonConsumableID || details.productID == IOSNonConsumableID) {
        _preferences.setBool("removeAd", true);
        debugPrint("splash: remove ad");
      } else {
        _preferences.setBool("removeAd", false);
        debugPrint("splash: not remove ad");
      }
    }
  }
```

But, in `if(response.error != null)` it does have error.
The message is `BillingResponse.serviceDisconnected`.
The code is `restore_transactions_failed`.
Detail was `null`.

Why does `iap.quertPastPurchases()` returned with error?
Is there any right way to check if user bought product?

Comment: Got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause.
As the `response.pastPurchases.length` was 0, it never iterated the for loop.